# `laravel-excel` how to create a table inside a cell?

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, laravel-excel

Suppose I have to write data a Microsoft Excel Workbook, I need to create a table with 5 rows and 4 columns, now in row 3 and column 4, I want to create a table with 3 column and 4 rows.

Using [`laravel-excel`](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) how can I achieve this? I have created the main table, but don't know how to create the inner table. Is it possible ?

Comment: How would you create an inner table inside a MS Excel cell?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I have reworded your question as it took me a couple of reads to understand what you are asking.  Your question would be much simpler to understand if you could draw us a diagram showing exactly what you want the output to be.